# Linq To SQL Overriding SubmitChanges Method (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I would like to run some code on every insert, update or delete in Linq To SQL.

Is the best way to do this to override the `SubmitChanges()` method?

Any code examples would help.

Comment: Someone explain why the down vote?

Comment: I don't think override is a good option. But there are plenty of alternatives. What code would be needed to run after the action (what do you wish the achieve)?

Comment: Basically add to a log file on every insert, update or delete. What other options are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. You can use `GetChangeSet` to retrieve the changes tracked by the datacontext.

```
Public Class MyDataContext
    Inherits MainDataContext

    Public Overrides Sub SubmitChanges(failureMode As System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode)
        Dim changes = GetChangeSet()
        MyBase.SubmitChanges(failureMode)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Clearly I wasn't thinking straight! Clean and easy to implement solution: +1

Comment: Does my code have to be above or below the `MyBase.SubmitChanges(failureMode)` line or does it not matter?

Comment: `GetChangeSet()` should run before. Your code could run after if you do not want to log anything if for example a crash happens or before if you do.